# GoogleTest - have several setUp() in one fixture

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, googletest

I am unittesting C++ code, and I am running complicated algorithm on huge data sets. I would like to have tests running on a first simple unrealistic dataset, and tests running on reality-like dataset. So, I would like my fixture to look like this:

```
class AppsToBeTested : public ::testing::Test 
{
public:
   AppsToBeTested():member(NULL)
   {

   }

   setUp1()
   {

   }

   setUp2()
   {

   }

   tearDown()
   {

   }
protected:
   helperCreateDataset1() ;
   helperCreateDataset2() ;

};
```

with `setUp2()` and `setUp2()` calling two different helper methods, `helperCreateDataset1()` and `helperCreateDataset2()` resp. In this version of the code, I am not overwriting `setUp()` method, but simply using two helpers `setUp1()` and `setUp2()` which I will have to call explicitely in the test cases.

What would be an appropriate way to have two setUp() initialization? Inheritance? Templates ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `gtest` documentation [here](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/V1_6_Primer#Basic_Concepts) hints to this response: one fixture is for one test environment for multiple test cases. All test cases sharing same fixture have same `setUp()`. If several setups are needed (eg. two types of setups for the test cases testing one class), then several fixtures should be used (eg. two fixtures, and test cases refering either to the first one or to the second one).

In short, I have the feeling that ONE FIXTURE == ONE SETUP, and use as many fixtures to test one class / one part of your code as the different setups you'll need.

Is this answer fair enough?

What is your opinion ?